# Why doesn't this simple Python script run?

Tags: python, global

I am writing a large program where I need to pass data/variables between functions. Note: I'm a hobbyist and OOP is out of my grasp, so just looking for a non-OOP answer!

I'm using functions to try and make the script modular and avoid having one long messy script. But the program uses a dataframe and lots of different variables which many of the functions will need to access. I don't want to specify every single variable in every function call so would like to be able to access global variables from individual functions. I can do this when the `def function():` is in the same script, but I am running into a problem when I try and call global variables when importing a function from a script. Simple reprex:

```
from test_func import p_func

a = "yes!"

p_func()
```

calling p_func() from test_func.py

```
def p_func():
    global a
    print(a)
```

generates the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    p_func()
  File "test_func.py", line 5, in p_func
    print(a)
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

What am I missing?

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: In Python, globals are only global to a single file.  If `p_func` needs the value of `a`, then you need to pass it as a parameter.  That is the RIGHT way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your import line to be:

```
from test_func import p_func, a
```

Variables are imported from other modules the same way that functions are.

That said.  This is really, really a bad idea as others above has said.  Your best off putting all your variables into a single data structure of some sort

Comment: I have all my key variable in a pandas dataframe, but how do I allow access to that data-frame for functions written outside of the core script?? It's clearly not feasible to push hundreds of variables to a every function I want to use outside of the core script. How to get round this without using globals?